# Navigator PushReplacementName gives back button in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, navigation, runtime-error, back

This is weird but below code is not working for me. I get a back arrow on the home screen when using below code.

First line below is for dismissing the dialog box. second one is to go to home screen.

```dart
 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomeScreen.id);
```

This is first time I am facing this kind of situation with `pushReplacementNamed`. what's going on here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably because you have another screen in the stack. When you call `pushReplacementNamed`, it doesn't replace whole stack with the one you give. Can you try the following code;

// true don't work based on above query condition

 `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(HomeScreen.id, (Route<dynamic> route) => true);`

// false works
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(HomeScreen.id, (Route<dynamic> route) => false);`

Answer (score 0):

That won't give the required result as you have already even popped the context away before calling another Navigator class. I tried the function `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()` but still got my HomeScreen pushed on stack twice with the back button on screen 1. Hence, I finally got this with the inbuilt function `Navigator.of(context).popUntil()`. You can run this **dartpad** code https://dartpad.dev/a10ed43452736b5c6b3d1abe6a7eda45 to view the desired effect or view the code below. Below is part of the code from the gist:

```
...
class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget{
  static const routeName = '/third';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    void _nextPage(){
      //Logic here - ***************************
   Navigator.of(context).popUntil((Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst);
  }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Third Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Third Page'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _nextPage,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Happy coding D:)

Comment: I have the same screen as 3rd screen when user logs in, it's before the home screen. so in that case how will this help. I want to completely replace the previously visited stack.